# PHP remove dir cannot remove because of permission

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to delete a folder using PHP however the folder is chmod -R 777 meaning that when PHP attempts to remove the folder it gets permission denied.

This is my delete function:

```
    private function delTree($dir)
{
    $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK );
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' )
            delTree( $file );
        else
            unlink( $file );
    }
    rmdir( $dir );
}
```

is it possible to work around sudo ? or add sudo permissions to the PHP function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have the directory still open after using `opendir()`. Especially when writing recursive functions for deleting directories, make sure you have `closedir()` **BEFORE** `rmdir()`.
However you don't need sudo when you set permissions `777`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have opened the folder with `opendir()` or `fopen()` then you're accessing the folder and you can't delete them when you have opened it or if you are insight the folder.

When you set the permission `777` its enough.